# How to append increment to the name dynamically?

Tags: powershell

I am creating DB/SSAS Cube snapshots for users weekly. For example, given "CubeABC", the user will find a snapshot of its previous iteration available to select as well:

```
CubeABC
CubeABC-Snapshot-06-28-2021-0400AM
```

I have recently enabled a feature that allows them to retain more than 1 snapshot, for example, if they specify the retention rate variable as 2, then 2 snapshots are retained at a time. If they change the retention to 1, then the OLDEST snapshot is deleted, and so forth on a weekly basis.

e.g. `retention_rate = 2`

```
CubeABC
CubeABC-Snapshot-06-28-2021-0400AM
CubeABC-Snapshot-07-05-2021-0400AM
```

e.g. `retention_rate = 1`

```
CubeABC
CubeABC-Snapshot-07-05-2021-0400AM
```

They connect to the cube in excel. However, there is a slight inconvenience that emerged: Since the Snapshots have a timestamp, and the timestamp continuously changes weekly, they have to edit the connection everytime to reflect the existing snapshot on the server, since the current one they were connected to say 2 or 3 weeks ago, e.g. `CubeABC-Snapshot-06-28-2021-0400AM` would be gone by now.

So I am considering the following idea:
append an "increment" instead of a timestamp to the snapshot:

```
CubeABC-Snapshot-1
CubeABC-Snapshot-2
```

etc..

where snapshot 1 in this case would be the oldest snapshot and snapshot 2 would be the most recent, assuming a `retention_rate = 2` that is.

How would I implement a "dynamic increment" (e.g. 1, 2), which replaces `$dateStamp` here: `$CUBE = "$CUBE-Snapshot-$dateStamp"`.

Here is the existing code I have:

```
#Check if there is existing snapshots first, and if there is, delete any snapshots > retention_rate

$matchingCubes = $AnalysisServer.Databases.Where({ $_.Name -like "*$CUBE-Snapshot*" })
if ($matchingCubes.Count -eq 0) { 
    Write-Host "`r`n No $CUBE Snapshot(s) found on $Target_Server server." -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor black
}
elseif($matchingCubes.Count -gt 0 -and $matchingCubes.Count -ge $retention_rate) {
    ($matchingCubes | Sort-Object Name -Descending | Select-Object -Skip ($retention_rate - 1)).Drop()

    Write-Host "`r`nThe following $CUBE Snapshot(s) were DELETED successfully from $Target_Server server!`r`n" -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor black
    Write-Host $($matchingCubes  -split "`n ")
}
else {
    Write-Host "`r`nNo $CUBE Snapshot(s) found older than $retention_rate retention interval(s) to Delete on $Target_Server server!" -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor black
    Write-Host "`r`nExisting $CUBE Snapshot(s) detected on $Target_Server server:`r`n"
    Write-Host $($matchingCubes  -split "`n ")
}

#Create New Snapshot
$CUBE = "$CUBE-Snapshot-$dateStamp"
Restore-ASDatabase -Server $Target_Server -RestoreFile $BFile -Name $CUBE -Security:$SecurityChoice -AllowOverwrite -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Why don't you sort `$matchingCubes.Name` by timestamp and then based on `retention_rate` you retain the newest ones found?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon that happens currently, what Im really looking to do is just change the naming of the snapshots instead of using timestamps i want to use increment so that the users dont have to change their connections every week, because with a timestamp that always changes, but an increment is constant. I included the retention logic just to provide full context but the magic I am looking for really showuld be happening here: `$CUBE = "$CUBE-Snapshot-$dateStamp"`

Comment: It seems like you just need to do this exercise just to rename all the snapshots and then implement the new naming scheme post-change? Or is some other process that you don’t own creating them as well?

Comment: @AdminOfThings i can rename the existing snapshots we have currently manually, there is not a whole lot of them anyways at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staying with your idea of using the increment in the snapshot name, I'm seeing something like the following after you manually rename the already existing snapshots to the new naming convention.

```
# Rename remaining snapshots
if ($retention_rate -ge 2){
    # get remaining Cube snapshots left after cleanup
    # $matchingCubes = **refreshed list of remaining cube snapshots (if needed)**.  Maybe Drop() does this already?
    
    # rename in order of age, oldest being renamed to $CUBE-Snapshot-1
    # sort ascending so that the highest number (oldest) is processed first    
    $matchingCubes | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 1} -Process {
        $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ("$CUBE-Snapshot-$(($i++))")
    }
}

#Create New Snapshot
# Newest Cube should have largest digit.  We can use $retention_rate
$CUBE = "$CUBE-Snapshot-$retention_rate"
Restore-ASDatabase -Server $Target_Server -RestoreFile $BFile -Name $CUBE -Security:$SecurityChoice -AllowOverwrite -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Aha..! Veeery interesting approach! So you're basically renaming existing snapshots based on sort and simply appending the value of retention rate to new snapshots. Veeery cool approach, it even takes care of renaming the current snapshots so that I don't have to do it manually, 2 birds w/ 1 stone!

Comment: oh dang, error :( `Rename-Item : Illegal characters in path. Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at '<DatabaseID>CubeABC-Snapshot-2</DatabaseID>' does not
exist.`

Comment: I don't know what your object types are in `$matchingCubes`.  If they are not [FileInfo] objects, then what are they?  You'll have to change the renaming part to be specific to however you would rename your object whatever it may be.

Comment: Using `GetType()`, This is the object type it seems: `BaseType: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Database`

Comment: ok so i found out that to rename SSAS Cubes, we have to first set the Name property to the name and then use the Update() method like so: `$matchingCubes | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object -Begin {$i = 1} -Process { $_.Name = "$CUBE-Snapshot-$(($i++))" $_.Update()}` however this poses a problem because ONLY the Name is changed, NOT the Cube ID! The Cube ID retains the existing name, so if the cube was named "CubeABC-Snapshot-2" then the ID will also be ""CubeABC-Snapshot-2" but we cannot rename the ID too! Bummer!This aproach won't work in since the restore operation overrides the ID